# Retrieve all documents but only specific fields from Cloudant database

Tags: database, select, cloudant

I want to return all the documents in a Cloudant database but only include some of the fields. I know that you can make a `GET` request against `https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/_all_docs`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to select only certain fields.

Alternatively , you can `POST` to `/db/_find` and include `selector` and `fields` in the JSON body. However, is there a universal selector, similar to `SELECT *` in SQL databases?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{"_id":{"$gt":0}}` as your `selector` to match all the documents, although you should note that it is not going to be performant on large data sets.

Comment: I'm using `{"_id": ( "$gt": null }}` which is mentioned in the docs, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a cleaner solution to get all the docs with only some fields included. You could always use Views and emit every doc, and the fields you want as the value in the map function.